# Git completion __git_ps1 really slow on Mac

Tags: macos, bash, git

I've had `__git_ps1` in my bash prompt for a while, but just recently (I noticed it after I did some messing around with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and rbenv), it has slowed down my prompt horribly. When I'm in a git directory I have to wait 3-4 seconds after every command for the prompt to appear.

If I just mash return and watch the Activity Monitor, it shows that distnoted and Finder are using more CPU than normal during the delay. Could something git-completion.bash is doing be triggering a notification to Finder? Maybe it involves folder actions or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a three-way interaction: rbenv was slowing down the rubygems version of the [hub](https://github.com/defunkt/hub) gem, which was aliased to git so it was slowing down __git_ps1. Switching to the new standalone version of hub fixed my problem.

Comment: Oh you are a life saver! That's exactly what my problem was. Removing the `alias git='hub'` fixed the problem! Awesome!

Comment: I should mention I don't use rbenv but I do use rvm. So rvm also interacts with the hub command.